# Different videos for different posts

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

I am a front end developer not with very backend stuff. I just wanted to know that I'm building a website and I need to provide options so that each personality on the website has different videos. What can I use instead of custom field or custom field plugins so that the admin can easily add or assign any video to any personality (which is a post type). There should be number of videos he can add and I will output 3 latest. Should there be any post type in which he can select the personality (post type) and add that video?

What do you guys suggest?

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a custom post type for videos paired with a custom taxonomy that matches the personalities.

Then you create the videos, categorize/tag them to the personality. Once they are tagged, create a template for the personality, write a custom `WP_Query()` that grabs your video posts filtered by the personality slug.